# How to set document.body.scrollHeight for unit testing in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test my function which calculates table height.

```
        self.tableHeight = function() {
            var tableContentOffsetTop = angular.element(document.getElementById("contentTable")).prop("offsetTop"),
                body = document.body,
                html = document.documentElement,
                clientHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight,
                                    body.offsetHeight,
                                    html.clientHeight,
                                    html.scrollHeight,
                                    html.offsetHeight);
            return (parseInt(clientHeight, 10) - tableContentOffsetTop);
        };
```

I tried to set the document height and also set the table offsetTop using

```
        document.body.scrollHeight = 1000;
        document.body.offsetHeight = 1000;
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight = 1000;
        document.documentElement.clientHeight = 1000;
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight = 1000;
       angular.element(document.getElementById("contentTable")).offSetTop = 250;
```

However I couldn't set the document Height as they already have some value and it wasn't getting overridden while I set the new height or offSetTop. Can anyone help me figure out how to unit test my function?. I am using jasmine for my unit testing.

Comment: I guess I was missing the px string which if I had would fix the unit tests.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue while doing unit testing. Please can you update your answer here? Thanks.

Comment: @RanjitSachin sorry I haven't been online late, I haven't tested my fix but if you had set the scrollHeight etc with px instead of numbers it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for reply Prashanth. I tried like below and its working. 
goog.style.setStyle(document.documentElement, {
    'height': '1280px'
  });